# Do discriminated unions only work with literal types?

Tags: typescript

In the snippet below, I'm not able to discriminate the union type using the `typeof` operator.

```
function f(arg: { status: number; one: boolean } | { status: string; two: boolean }) {
    if (typeof arg.status === "number") {
        return arg // arg is still of the union type and is not narrowed
    } else {
        return arg // similar here
    }
}
```

But if `status` is changed to some literal type, then the union can be discriminated.

```
function f(arg: { status: "one"; one: boolean } | { status: "two"; two: boolean }) {
    if (arg.status=== "one") {
        return arg // here arg is of type { status: "one"; one: boolean }
    } else {
        return arg // and here it's of type { status: "two"; two: boolean }
    }
}
```

So, I wanted to know why does it *not* work in the first case, is it that discriminated unions only work with literal types *or* is there something else?

I tried to find in the docs to see if it's mentioned somewhere that discriminated unions only work with literal types but I couldn't find anything.

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjACgIYCcDmAuRAb0QGcoMoQSCwQBbAIwFMsBuRBJghuOAGyYYkAX0QAfIqXKVqUrDDA52UAO5xuvAUMTCAlEQCwAKESnEMYIjRQAngAcmcS9hwA6MhSqIAvL8QAiWkYWf31CYzNIxCwmSiwkF0QAeiTERJgSKRg+Pg5LKAALJkRweCRbBzSwABNzTLA4KEQwbCw4FSZqiLNRJj4SYvCTKNMYuITcZNSSGDps7EQimO7TYWM1o2NQSFgEZAAmTFwCYgquZpAc9k4NfkERcUkzgn3lNVutETCV80sjtzOPj8+2+wxGYxA8TSkxSixYxXSmSciEBp3s538nH81zA5x4d20G0ivX6gx+kQhUMSsKEtSWxRgUAA5Ej8uinuiCP5VHBsSj3oh8Z8dD8NsIgA)

Comment: What version of TypeScript? Also, include your `tsconfig.json`. I'm not able to recreate this.

Comment: @John Added a link to TS Playground

Comment: I can reproduce easily, and this is how discriminated unions in TS behave, so I think @John should double check what's going on in their own environment.

Comment: To answer this question: yes, this is working as intended. A discriminant property needs to have a literal/singleton type, in at least one of the members.  The docs *used* to mention literal types ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)), and [the TS3.2 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants) give more info.  I can write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is kind of a limitation that Typescript currently has. It's been discussed a few times in the Typescript Github [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) so I'll use some of the responses from there.

First, you should know [that](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31755#issuecomment-498669080):

> Type guards do not propagate type narrowings to parent objects. The
> narrowing is only applied upon access of the narrowed property which
> is why the destructing function works, but the reference function does
> not. Narrowing the parent would involve synthesizing new types which
> would be expensive.

So basically if you used the code below, you'd see that TS indeed is able to narrow down the type of that specific property:

```
function f1(arg: { status: number; one: boolean } | { status: string; two: boolean }) {
    if (typeof arg.status === "number") {
        const st = arg.status // st: number
    }
}
```

> Narrowing the parent object is only done in specific scenarios, when
> the property is considered a discriminant for the union. A property is
> considered as a discriminant property if:
>
> 1- The property is a literal type as outlined here [Discriminated union
> types.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163)
>
> 2- The a property of a union type to be a discriminant property if it has
> a union type containing at least one unit type and no instantiable
> types as outlined here [Allow non-unit types in union discriminants](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695).

For more info, you could see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31755).