# union type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, object, union-types

TypeScript: How can I access values from a union type in TypeScript when the specific type is not known until runtime? Specifically, I have a union type of different objects with different keys, and I want to access a specific key from the object based on a string value, but TypeScript gives me an error because the string value could potentially belong to any of the objects in the union. How can I properly access the key in a type-safe manner?

```
export type NAV_BAR_CRISIS_TYPE =
    {
        details: "פרטי אירוע",
        jeep: "מתנדבים",
        rescuers: "מחולצים",
        log: "יומן אירוע",
        telegram: 'שיחת טלגרם',
        gallery: 'גלריה'
    };

export type NAV_BAR_VOLUNTEER_TYPE = {
    volunteer: "פרטי מתנדב",
    jeep: "פרטי רכב",
    phone: "פרטי קשר",
    medical: "פרטים רפואיים",
    qualifications: 'הכשרות',
    interview: 'תהליך קליטה',
    report: 'דו"ח פעילות'
};

export type NAV_BAR_OTHER_ACTIVITIES_TYPE = {
    details: 'פרטי אירוע',
    participants: 'משתתפים'
}

propsTitles: NAV_BAR_CRISIS_TYPE | NAV_BAR_OTHER_ACTIVITIES_TYPE | NAV_BAR_VOLUNTEER_TYPE

<BottomNavigationAction
            showLabel
            label={Object.keys(propsTitles).includes(value) && propsTitles[value]}
            value={value}
            className={clsx("nav_bar_item", `nav_bar_${String(value)}`, { nav_bar_item_active: isActive })}
            icon={
                <img
                    className="nav_bar_icon"
                    src={src}
                    alt={String(value)}
                />
            }
            onClick={() => onClick(value)}
        />
```

```
label={typeof value === 'string' && Object.keys(propsTitles).includes(value) && propsTitles[value as keyof propsTitles]}
```

the Error that appers is:

> 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'NAV_BAR_CRISIS_TYPE | NAV_BAR_OTHER_ACTIVITIES_TYPE | NAV_BAR_VOLUNTEER_TYPE'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'NAV_BAR_CRISIS_TYPE | NAV_BAR_OTHER_ACTIVITIES_TYPE | NAV_BAR_VOLUNTEER_TYPE'.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do discriminated unions only work with literal types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199307/do-discriminated-unions-only-work-with-literal-types)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [ask] and consider providing a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Right now it seems to depend on `BottomNavigationAction` and a bunch of undeclared values, and so I have a lot of errors, none of which are the one you're talking about.  If you make it easy for others to work on, it will be easier for them to give you a useful answer.  Also it might be better to remove any non-English text unless you're asking about translations, since it's at best distracting from your issue.

Comment: `propsTitles[value as keyof typeof propsTitles];`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to tell TS when you are sure what type `value` is (you almost had it, but you need to turn `propsTitles` into a type with `typeof`):

```
Object.keys(propsTitles).includes(value) && propsTitles[value as keyof typeof propsTitles]
Object.keys(propsTitles).includes(value) && propsTitles[value as keyof (NAV_BAR_CRISIS_TYPE | NAV_BAR_OTHER_ACTIVITIES_TYPE | NAV_BAR_VOLUNTEER_TYPE)]
```

A second solution is to define a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), which is a function that uses the `is` operator in its return type and makes TS narrow down the type:

```
function isKeyofPropsTitle(s:string): s is keyof typeof propsTitles {
  return s in propsTitles
}
```

Now you can write it (almost) as before, without having to cast:

```
isKeyofPropsTitle(value) && propsTitles[value]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByBBAagfQEIYBKOAwoQJIDKVOAKgJoAKAonALwBQc3cA3lz0EATYDACGASwA2AZwBccAESAT0EAXoIA3QQJugcQAugm1YFXQQEegigDQDB3AFbBgYBYsB7oICvQQAeggZdBAi6CbAu6BmLllDAMgDGAK7AUPJKjoDroAaAO6CAZ6C+-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-7ikuYQiOBj7vMAsFwAAZFhcCQTue4HsEADaaERAAunAAD0VFwJEW5QNwn4-sAf5ASB4H4dBREyPBiHvChYFkRh2G4VxhGHqRT6oGItbAYgEBsjsKCKXhW4ETBwSUTRcAytAgHnt+v4AfJnHqdxcEIR8SGCcJmE4WpUESSRwlwLJcDyapYHjm6TbUMOEajp2Dbul6Pr9oGwbkKG4YPGOLoTlOlzXD6rawdptEyPUMm1mIX4QM8wDrGynx-jyHxwBIMgANIgYpjDmc5YHyK+76wS+lVyXVSnlqp4mabW-DcEEMBhFAFW1uKjkaTxHBLOsVW1QpbINU5mlCdJ9liY1A1SehGW6fptZAA)